# Dragging custom window title bar from top when maximized does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, window, customization, titlebar

I have a custom title bar and with the window style set to none.  On the click of the title bar I check to see if it is a double click (that does window maximize and restore) if it is not double clicked I do `Window.DragMove`. This works great for the snapping to the side and top.  But when I try to drag the window when it is maximized (which would normally restore the window down), it doesn't do anything.  Here is my code:

```
    static Window Window { get { return Application.Current.MainWindow; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// TitleBar_MouseDown - Drag if single-click, resize if double-click
    /// </summary>
    private static void TitleBar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            if (e.ClickCount == 2)
            {
                AdjustWindowSize();
            }
            else
            {
                Window.DragMove();//Here is where I do the drag move
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adjusts the WindowSize to correct parameters when Maximize button is clicked
    /// </summary>
    internal static void AdjustWindowSize()
    {
        if (Window.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(Window);
        }
        else
        {
            SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(Window);
        }

    }

    #region Button Events

    /// <summary>
    /// CloseButton_Clicked
    /// </summary>
    public static void Close()
    {
        SystemCommands.CloseWindow(Window);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// MaximizedButton_Clicked
    /// </summary>
    public static void Maximize()
    {
        AdjustWindowSize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Minimized Button_Clicked
    /// </summary>
    public static void Minimize()
    {
        SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(Window);
    }

    #endregion
```

Modern UI and MahApps.Metro does it somehow and I looked at their source code briefly but could not find how they do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I am able to get the desired behavior of title bar including aero snap in pure xaml

as result you can see a custom title bar, it is completely draggable, double click to maximize and restore and drag to snap and unsnap.

**xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="CSharpWPF.MainWindow" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" >
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=titlebar}"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Border Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25" x:Name="titlebar">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window},FallbackValue=Title}" 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="White" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                </TextBlock.Effect>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4">
            <TextBlock Text="Window content"/>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

result

[image: result]

so now you don't need any code behind to handle title bar manually.

**Reusable styles**

you can also wrap above in a custom style which you can apply on several windows

```xml
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="CustomTitleBar">
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Border Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                            Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}" x:Name="titlebar">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" 
                                        Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="White" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                                </TextBlock.Effect>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="LightGray" 
                            BorderThickness="1" Padding="4">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

usage

```xml
<Window x:Class="CSharpWPF.View" 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                Title="MainWindow" 
                Style="{StaticResource CustomTitleBar}" >
    <TextBlock Text="Window content"/>
</Window>
```

---

**`How to implement in your code`**

After looking at your code, I did manage to implement it with very little changes

Changes are

**File:** `CustomChrome.cs`

line 41: change `CaptionHeight = 36`, currently it is 0. this should be equal to your title bar height

```
var chrome = new WindowChrome() { GlassFrameThickness = new Thickness(-1), CaptionHeight = 36 };
```

line 60: remove `((FrameworkElement)sender).MouseDown += TitleBar_MouseDown;` as not required

line 70: remove no more used event `TitleBar_MouseDown`

**File:** `CornerButtons.xaml`

line 13: add `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"` to `StackPanel`

```
    <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Orientation="Horizontal" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
```

**File:** `MainWindow.xaml`

line 17: add `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"` to `StackPanel`

```
<cc:CornerButtons Grid.Column="2">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
```

this is all, and your app will have a normal title bar without need to handle custom logic

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. It did some funky stuff then.

Comment: could you post a working sample of your app? may I try it here.

Comment: do you know how to do that?

Comment: If you want to know how to post then simply zip the code files and upload to a file sharing site then post the link here. If you look look forward for code only, I may give it a shot.

Comment: here is the link: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A01D9CF82243C1CC!14297&authkey=!ANNLNI9kPtjiZ_4&ithint=folder%2c.sln

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, because that covers the buttons (close, minimize, restore).  I cant click them then.

Comment: did you set `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"`, this is necessary for those button to work. you can set individually to the buttons too.

Comment: I updated my answer, see `MainWindow.xaml` in answer, this will enable the ComboBox and the Button from the main window too.

Comment: I made the changes in your code for you, download it here [WPFControls.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPcXFSd3JOdVh1OFk/edit?usp=sharing). this includes all the mentioned changes and seems to we working as your expectations including aero snap / unsnap, title bar buttons, combo etc.

Comment: this solution only works for 4.5 tho? in 3.5, 4.0 WindowChrome seems nonexistant. In addition to that the measurements for the window are not correct if you maximize it this way it seems. i've added a dockpanel inside the content area with background-color. too bad. a pure xaml solution would have been neat

Comment: in 4.0 you can use [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/). secondly when window is maximized the resize border is placed outside of the screen. so you may perhaps add the padding based on the `ResizeBorderThickness` property of `WindowChrome` when the window is maximized.

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix, Thanks

Comment: Custom window works great however it missing little animations when you maximize and minimize window it just popup suddenly and hide suddenly. Do you know how to accomplish default minimize and maximize effect.

Comment: @UzairAli, the custom window will usually follow system animation settings. I tried it on Win 8 and it animates similar to any other window. Try enabling window animations in system properties. If you still see the same. Please create and new question for the same and provide me the link to the same.

Comment: In case of using WindowChrome object you should make sure ResizeBorderThickness = 0 at Maximized windows state. Otherwise you will not be able to unsnap the window by dragging it at the very top.