# Style border and Title Bar cause NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I want to change my `form` border and Title Bar and fount [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654845/c-sharp-wpf-custom-title-bar-drag-window-from-top-when-maximized-doesnt-wo) solution.
So after add this into my `XAML` (i am using the first solution in the first answer) my application running and i can see the `Style` changed but after few seconds i can see this exception in the designer:

[image]

My application still run and show the new style but this is happening again and again, i try to remove and add changes several times but this error still jump after a while.
    Update

this is the code that added to `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="CSharpWPF.MainWindow" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" >
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=titlebar}"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Border Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25" x:Name="titlebar">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window},FallbackValue=Title}" 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="White" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                </TextBlock.Effect>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4">
            <TextBlock Text="Window content"/>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Paste some code which generate exception.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. have you tried updating your Visual Studio to latest version ?

Comment: that's fishy cause this is not happening all the time

Comment: The exception is coming from `TitleBar_Loaded`, and that method is not part of the code shown in the other answer, nor part of the code you've added to your question. Did you add that method? What are you doing inside? Care to share the code with us?

Comment: I agreed with @almulo. Paste TitleBar_Loaded method. Look at first line (in fact it's third of course :)) of your stack trace. It points to TitleBar_Loaded method.